# Format SQL output in Powershell ISE

Tags: sql, powershell

Using Invoke-SQLCMD and running a saved query, Is there a way to see the output as a table? Currently, All output is printed sequentially, such as Name *newline* state *newline* is_encrypted for each item returned from the query rather than a row-column table where name, state, is_encrypted, etc. are the column headers.

The end goal is to output all the results of the query into a text or excel file.

Comment: Have you tried Out-File cmdlet?

Comment: Piping to `Export-Csv` should also work

Comment: Fantastic, should have thought about that first but it works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -query $sql | Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\excelfile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```